# Why does combining two `data.frame` objects using the `data.frame` function cut off a long variable name?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have noticed that if I try to combine two different `data.frame` objects into a larger `data.frame` using the `data.frame` function, the variable names are cut off (i.e. see output of `names(db)` from code below.

I currently avoid the situation by combining the variables using the `data.table` function instead.

My question is:

Why does the `data.frame` command cut off my variable names? This may be quite a simple question, and can be solved easily by using the `as.data.frame` function on the `data.table` object to convert it back to a `data.frame`, but I am very curious as to why the variable names are cut off in the first place if I just use the `data.frame` function. I have tried looking for an insight into this using the help in R, and on Google, but have found no success so far. I am seeking an answer more to help me better understand how R, and `data.table` and `data.frame` works (as I am a relatively new R user, having recently switched from Stata).

Thanks in advance!

```
> a <- data.frame(rnorm(100))
> b <- data.frame(rnorm(100))
> names(a) <- "thisisaveryverylongvariablename-mean()"
> names(b) <- "thisisanotherveryverylongvariablename-std()"
> db <- data.frame(a, b)
> names(db)
[1] "thisisaveryverylongvariablename.mean.."      "thisisanotherveryverylongvariablename.std.."
> names(c(a, b))
[1] "thisisaveryverylongvariablename-mean()"      "thisisanotherveryverylongvariablename-std()"
> db2 <- data.table(a, b)
> names(db2)
[1] "thisisaveryverylongvariablename-mean()"      "thisisanotherveryverylongvariablename-std()"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable names are not cut-off; simply, they are made more "compatible" with the R environment. You can override this with the `check.names=FALSE` argument to `data.frame()`:

```
a <- data.frame(rnorm(100))
b <- data.frame(rnorm(100))
names(a) <- "thisisaveryverylongvariablename-mean()"
names(b) <- "thisisanotherveryverylongvariablename-std()"
db <- data.frame(a, b, check.names = FALSE)
names(db)
# [1] "thisisaveryverylongvariablename-mean()"      "thisisanotherveryverylongvariablename-std()"
```